# How to move around a Path object inside Canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf

How I can change a path position on my canvas. It don't moves by Canvas.Left/Top/Right/Bottom properties and it has not X, not Y.
If anyone know how it do, help me please.
For example: I have some path and I need change position for him programatically.

```
<Canvas>
    <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="10">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathFigureCollection>    
                        <PathFigure StartPoint="100,80">
                            <PathFigure.Segments>
                                <PathSegmentCollection>
                                    <PolyBezierSegment Points="90,200 140,200 160,200 180,200 430,190 430,280" />
                                </PathSegmentCollection>
                            </PathFigure.Segments>
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathFigureCollection>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Please provide some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have `X` nor `Y` properties, because a Path object does not really care much **where** it sits in.

You can place a Path inside a Canvas, or inside a Grid, or inside a StackPanel. Why would a Path need X/Y when it is put in a Grid that lays out the items with columns and rows? Same reasoning goes for Grid and its Columns and Rows. The Path does not have Grid-related `Column` or `Row` properties either, right?

Those settings are set by so-called **attached properties**. The Canvas define properties like `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` that you can use to position your Path inside Canvas. It works just the same way as Grid and `Grid.Column`/`Grid.Row` properties.

Actually, it's worth noting that Canvas provide you not with X/Y attached properties, but rather **Left/Right** and **Top/Bottom**, that allow you to choose where the position is aligned to.

XAML:

```
<Canvas>
    <Path x:Name="mypath" Canvas.Left="50" Canvas.Top="25" .... />
</Canvas>
```

C#:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(mypath, 50.0);
Canvas.SetTop(mypath, 25.0);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. It will be good, but Canvas.SetLeft(mypath, 50.0); always returns NaN. It working if use path.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), canvas); in place of Canvas.SetLeft(mypath, 50.0); and Canvas.SetTop(mypath, 25.0);

Comment: @dremerDT: You must have done something wrong or very odd. First of all, SetLeft and SetTop both return VOID (https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.setleft(v=vs.110).aspx) so where did you get the NaN from?

Comment: @dremerDT: Second, the `TranslatePoint` is different from SetLeft/Top/etc. It is used to calculate the coordinate mapping ("offset") between two UI elements. `path.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), canvas);` would take point `(0, 0)` in Shape's coordinate space and recalculate it into Canvas coordinate space, and (assuming the Path is placed **directly** on that Canvas) it would result in a point equal to `(Canvas.GetLeft(path), Canvas.GetTop(path)).`. You don't need to `TranslatePoint`. You can simply use GetLeft/GetTop. Of course, it's not much of an error. In this case, result is the same.

Comment: I'm sorry. I was very tired. Not SetLeft/SetTop, GetLeft/GetTop return NaN.

Comment: @dremerDT: GetLeft/GetTop return whatever value was **previously** set on the item in Canvas. If you call SetLeft with (path,50.0), then later GetLeft(on-that-path) will return 50.0. "Previously" word is very important, because it implies that if you `GetLeft` on something what didn't have any value set, you **will get NaN**. There is no default value, i.e. 'zero'. There is **no value** as default at all.  This kept consistent across whole WPF. The same stands for example for Width/Height properties (if not set = NaN) and that's why you've also have ActualWidth/ActualHeight (=RenderSize)

Comment: If you observe NaNs, then you must have forgotten to set the position at some point. Either: (A) ensure that every item has Left/Top set at some initial moment, i.e. when it is first put into Canvas, or (B) when seeing NaN, default it to safe initial value as 0.0, 50.0, 100.0, or whatever-fits-your-layout, or both A+B :)

Comment: Thanks you, I solved the problem. In a mouseDown event on the Path I use path.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), canvas); and keep position, then in a mouseMove event I use Canvas.SetTop/SetLeft for changing position.